# .htaccess rule to redirect 'domain.tld.' to 'domain.tld'

Tags: .htaccess

I've scoured Google and this site pretty extensively, and I must be missing something. None of the suggestions I've found worked.

The problem is simple. I have links coming in to my site using `http://domain.name./` but I want all visitors redirected to `http://domain.name/` without the trailing dot.

How can I do that?

Comment: `domain.name.` is not even a valid domain name. If I were you, I'd try to find the root cause rather than masking it with a redirect.

Comment: @ Álvaro it is valid. Each segment of a domain name may end with a dot. The last one is just optional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)\.$
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]
```